# Nothing shows up in my Android Studio Logcat

Tags: android

I'm working on a project for my Android class using the latest version of Android Studio (3.4.1) and my app isn't working right. I can't see what's going wrong because nothing shows up in the Logcat.

I'm running my app on a physical phone since Android Studio doesn't like AMD. I have "Show only selected application" selected and it shows my phone is connected. I tried restarting Logcat, but that didn't do anything. 
[screenshot to show my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5X0j.png)

Comment: it happens sometime. I usually connect and disconnect device and it works

Comment: That works sometimes, but not every time. Right now it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

**Just try** ,Invalidate and Restart Android Studio or Restart Android Studio.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the device connected. Open terminal from below. Type following command to kill and start adb.

```
adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
```

If the command doesn't work, you will need to fire it from `/sdk/platform tools/`

Comment: I put that command in the terminal and it says: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.